# Oops!!! Dropped it again!

Tags: cipher

I have dropped my laptop twice in the past and luckily nothing went wrong. Today while getting ready for college, I dropped it again - for the third time. This time,  something is wrong. When I switched it on, it just displayed the below text. Can you find what does it say ?

[image]

@Stiv has almost got it.

Hint

> A complement to .......

Comment: If you look at it upside-down then everything makes another letter or number except A.

Comment: The letters and numbers also fall neatly into hex pairs b2 89 8E 9A 93 94 but I'm not making any further progress with that at the moment. Maybe '3 times' is significant, e.g. 3 conversions?

Comment: You're almost there!!!! @stiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text is

> Python

Solution:

> The hint was really helpful here. Thanks to @Stiv's insight, this forms six hexadecimal pairs, which are numbers between 0 and 255 inclusive. Then, taking the hint into consideration, take the **complement** of each number (flip the bits from 1 to 0 and vice versa). The dropping three times part was also important; you add 3 to each of these 6 numbers. Finally, these are ASCII codes for the string "Python".

Cool challenge!

This is how I solved it: https://tio.run/##PY29DoIwGEVn@xR3pHoHFAcxcUB@XsJoUqCVDgJpGPTpEdqE5ZyzfN8df1M39Mk8K6ImGqIlNGFwQ/ytT1x4ST31ylR5Jp5nIUZn@ylSrNmwpaaRQmTEnciJgiiJyr8yBi/4Y1/1Vs1W7VZ6KyOEGRwsbA@n@reOjrG8il3Y3X/UGDWdIx4ZDrDLcFAeVASVQdWqp5Tz/Ac

Comment: Excellent......

Comment: And it's an OOP......

Comment: @Ak19 ? (the only meaning of OOP i know is Object-Oriented Programming and I'm not sure that's what you meant)

Comment: Yeah, I meant the same. The title has OOPs.